# Appending 2D array to a list of arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

My code has a problem. I know what the problem is.
I cant append an array to another array with the append method.

I need to find something else. What is an effective and not complicated way to append an array to an array?

This code should plot the trajectory of a ball that is fired from different angles ( 5 to 85 degrees).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = np.arange(5,86,5)

v0 = 30
Cd = 1.2
A = 0.02
M = 1.5
gvec = np.array([0,-9.813])
rho = 1.225
dt = 0.01

for a in alpha:
    xvec = np.array([0.0,0.0])
    vvec = v0 * np.array([np.cos(a),np.sin(a)])
    xall = []

    while xvec[1] > 0:
        V = np.sqrt(np.sum(vvec*vvec))
        Dvec = -0.5 * rho * Cd * A * V**2 * vvec /V
        accvec = gvec + Dvec/M
        vvec = vvec + accvec*dt
        xvec = xvec + vvec*dt
        xall.append(xvec)

    xall = np.array(xall)

    plt.plot(xall[:,0] ,xall[:,1])

plt.show()
```

I would like to create an array " xall"  in the following format.
xall are all the coordinates. so this is what i want.

`xall = array([x1,y1], [x2,y2], ....... , [xn, yn])`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok, but the condition of while is somehow wrong.

```
    xvec = np.array([0.0,0.0])
    vvec = v0 * np.array([np.cos(a),np.sin(a)])
    xall = []

    while xvec[1] > 0:
```

Since you define xvec as many 0's array, the condition for while is not met and just passed. Once you include `xvec[1] = 0`, you can obtain a plot.

Btw, the sin and cos function treats the angle as radian, so you have to modify a bit

```
    vvec = v0 * np.array([np.cos(np.pi * a / 180), np.sin(np.pi * a / 180)])
```

and the result will be:

[image]